# Differential eqution of 2nd order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(x\sin x + \cos x)y''-(x\cos x)y' +y\cos x = 0$ with $y(x)=x$ being a solution.

Solved by change of dependent variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've found one solution, you can employ a reduction of order to find the other. Assume the second solution is of the form $y = x*v(x)$, where $x$ was the first solution.
$$[x\sin(x) + \cos(x)]y" - x\cos(x)y' + \cos(x)y = 0$$
$$[x\sin(x) + \cos(x)](2v' + xv'') - x\cos(x)(v + xv') + \cos(x)xv = 0$$
$$[x\sin(x) + \cos(x)](2v' + xv'') - x^2\cos(x)v' = 0$$
Notice there is now no $v$ term. This becomes a first order DE and is much easier to solve.

Comment: I too had done this but can't go further

Comment: It is solved thank you bdw